# 2sxc | Display multiple files with Adam upload

Tags: 2sxc

I can upload multiple files (documents in this case) at the same time very well. Is it possible to have a hyperlink field with multiple adam files dropped into it or even a plus ('+') icon to add another without having to drop on another app each time?

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Sorry I overlooked ADAM 1.2 (link below) feature to use hyperlink 'Library' for multi file selection.

https://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/introducing-adam-1-2-with-folders-metadata-and-c-sharp-api

I have been able multi select now but still having difficulty with using the file picker to create the folder structure I wish to achieve:

[image]

I read from link above:

> 4. You can create even another content-type - like Application Group Metadata - which you can use as folder-metadata. This allows the editor to tag each folder with additional information.

I do not fully understand how to use this 'folder-metadata' to achieve the same thing as the file manager allows me to do by specifying where each file is to be stored?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you add more context, to explain what you're trying to achieve? Best to use real terms like "I have a site which shows dogs, and these dogs should..."

Comment: Adam upload facilitates batch uploading to file management but only allows 1 image/document to be selected at a given time. This is a slow process when dealing with sites that require 1000+ files to be uploaded. My question was there a way to allow the hyperlink field input (ie the Adam upload field above) to select 10+ images/docs at the same time as its currently taking a long time for each document to open UI admin and select a single document/image each time (kind of undoes the batch upload facility by not allowing batch selection)

Comment: sorry, still confused. you can drag in hundreds of files at the same time. You want to upload many files to different targets at the same time?

Comment: So is the initial question already answered with the library, but you have a different question about metadata?

Comment: Yes I wanted to select (show to screen) multiple files at same time as Adam multiple upload which answers my initial question (although with the 'Show File Manager' option not working, my issue persists!). I will create a new question for metadata, thx